# WebKitX: How do I get the OnFrameLoad event?

Tags: chromium

CefSharp provides the [OnFrameLoad event](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_ILoadHandler_OnFrameLoadStart.htm): https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_ILoadHandler_OnFrameLoadStart.htm

I am using WebKitX by mobilefx.
I have not found this event or any way to get this event.
How can I achieve this using WebKitX, or can WebKitX not do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event does not exist, and the developer does not add it.

I was able to use VB6 Webview2 instead:

https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?889202-VB6-WebView2-Binding-(Edge-Chromium)&p=5597424#post5597424

The good thing is that this also resolved occasional crashes that I experienced with the above control.